# Excel - How to create an array of every occurrence based on a condition

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, lookup

Looking for a non-VBA solution if possible.

Let's say we have 2 tables, 1 contains Tags and P&IDNumbers, and the other contains P&IDNumbers and an empty set of cells.

[image: Table1]

I'm looking to see if it's possible to use an excel formula to lookup every Tag which had a certain PIDNumber and place them into an array in a single cell, as shown below:

[image: Table2]

Items like Vlookup only return the first iteration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `TEXTJOIN()` function with `FILTER()` function

Comment: Ahh yep, that worked thanks!

Answer formula for the above was:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A1:A8,B1:B8=D2))

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it, perhaps using `GROUPBY()`

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(B2:B8,A2:A8,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($A$2:$A$8,D2=$B$2:$B$8))
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT($A$2:$A$8,D2=$B$2:$B$8))
```

---

Or,

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(D2=$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,""))
```

---

Or,

```
=PIVOTBY(B2:B8,,A2:A8,ARRAYTOTEXT,0,0)
```

---

```
=LET(α, SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B8)),HSTACK(α, BYROW(α,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(B2:B8=x,A2:A8,""))))))
```

---